# Delete the closed question

Tags: support, closed-questions, deletion, deleted-questions

My First question didn't fall in criteria of Skeptics and was closed. This helped me understand what should be asked here and what should be not. After a week or so, i still see my closed question existing in the database and everyone has access to it other than the ability to provide answers.

Same thing applies to other closed questions. So my question or rather a point is why aren't we deleting the closed questions. In case we need to keep them, then make a weekly deadline; crossing which, the question is deleted itself.

**I think the site is enough mature and enough questions to make people understand the real essence of Skeptics.** Therefore, the closed questions should be removed from the database for achieving a meaningful and knowledgeable database.

Answer (score 2):

We moderators occasionally go through the older closed questions and delete those that serve no purpose anymore. See [this answer from Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete) for more guidelines on when to delete.

We're not doing that systematically and we usually don't want to delete immediately after closing to give the community a chance to revert the decision and to give the user enough time to understand why it was closed.

You can help cleaning up by voting to delete old closed questions or by flagging them if you don't have the delete privilege.

Comment: Actually on every question page, i come across 2-3 or even more closed questions. So, i thought there isn't any regulating process for these questions.

**Thanks for clearing the air**